# Bootstrap: ol + li + div.col-md-6 = displaced

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to replace my table structure with an `<ol>` tag.
But there is always a displacement/offset between the leading order number and the content.

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">A Name</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">An Icon</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

I have no idea what to change. When I debug with Firebug I can't see any padding or margin that causes this behaviour.

Is there anything else I can do to get those two columns or two divs in one line with the leading number?

Comment: Could you please clarify your issue? What is "leading order number" and what is "content"?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap grid system, then you can remove your `ol li` structure and just go ahead with the `row`.

But if you really need to use your `ol li`, then you need to remove the default `list-style-type` and default `margin` from `ol`.

```
ol.ol-table { /* Assuming you assign a class to it  */
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Check out the result: http://jsfiddle.net/uyJXe/embedded/result/

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uyJXe/